# Converting polygon ribbons to strand primitives

Tags: hair

I'm a total Blender newbie (first post here). I'd like to ask if there is a method, or a script, that allows me to convert a geometry consisting of polygon ribbons (so basically hairs, where each hair is made of n quads), into Blender strand primitives.
Thanks for any help.